# Print a doc From Android Mobile using wirelessprinters

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee, printing

I want to print an receipt from my application using wireless printers. So how can i do it ?
any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use classes in [android.print](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/package-summary.html) package

You need to make your print document adapter class derived from [PrintDocumentAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html)
This class is responsible for your printed document contents.

To perform print:

```
 // create and initalize your PrintDocumentAdapter
 ...

 // obtrain PrintManager instance
 PrintManager printManager =
     (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);

 // build PrintAttributes
 PrintAttributes.Builder builder = new PrintAttributes.Builder();
 builder. <set your print attributes such as: color/monochrome, media size, min margins>

 // print document 
 printManager.print(yourPrintJobName, yourPrintDocumentAdapter, builder.build());
```

Note: android.print require API level 19 and higher.